# Airline Code-Share Baggage Policy: Which Airline baggage policy apply on my first flight?

Tags: bookings, airlines, qatar-airways

I have booked a one-way ticket from the Qatar Airways website. Do I have the same baggage policy in all my flights or different policies will apply to the Alaska Airline & Qatar Airways?
First flight departs from SFO, United States.

And I also wanna know, if I would need to recheck my baggage after changing airline or they will be directly forwarded to my final destination? Thanks

P.S: I searched already on the internet and found so many conflicting answers. Hopefully, I get a clear one here.

[image: Booking Copy]

Answer (score 5):

As per [U.S. DOT Regulation §399.87: Baggage allowances and fees](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c6da7d48f43ec3a0f9227c6a41c5371c&mc=true&node=se14.4.399_187&rgn=div8):

> For passengers whose ultimate ticketed origin or destination is a U.S. point, U.S. and foreign carriers must apply the baggage allowances and fees that apply at the beginning of a passenger's itinerary **throughout his or her entire itinerary**.

This means that the baggage allowance cannot change throughout the journey; there must be only one single baggage allowance that applies to the entire journey.

Also, as per [IATA Resolution 302](https://www.jal.co.jp/en/other/info2011_0304iata.html), the baggage policy of the marketing carrier of the most significant route (the first to cross continental "zones", in this case the BOS-DOH segment) applies to the entire journey.

In this case, the marketing carrier of that flight is Qatar Airways (since that flight is noted as a QR flight on your booking confirmation), and their policy for journeys to and from the U.S. is [two free bags, weighing 23 kilograms](https://www.qatarairways.com/en/baggage/allowance.html).

Therefore, for your entire itinerary, you should be allowed to check two free bags, weighing a maximum of 23 kilograms each.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the detailed answer. Do you know If I would need to recheck my bag when my airline changes or they will be directly forwarded to my destination?

Comment: It largely depends on the airport/airline and if there is a customs control point, @AliAhmed. Usually, if you bought it all on one ticket and there's no customs or border control to pass (sometimes you may even need a transit visa), it'll be automatically forwarded. For the 100% safe answer check with the airline you are flying with - either in-flight attendants or ground staff.

Comment: @CesarM This doesn't apply here, but the exception is if your transit is in a country that doesn't legally have sterile transit, e.g. the U.S.

Comment: Also true, thanks for adding! I'll edit the comment to reflect Customs or Border Control.